# How do I force a Flex ComboBox's labelFunction to be called for the selected item when locale changes?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a ComboBox with a label function like this one:

```
private function fieldLabelFunction(item:Object):String {
    return resourceManager.getString('dashboard',"SS." + item);
}
```

When I change locales, the labels display correctly in the ComboBox's dropdown list, or if I change a selection. However, the currently selected item's label doesn't refresh at first.

Is there a way to force the labelFunction to get called again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the dataProvider is an ArrayCollection (or ListCollectionView), 
you can try to call refresh() on it after the Locale is changed.

I think this triggers the labelFunction to be called again.

From the behaviour you describe, this might also be a Flex bug.

hth

Koen